# SDN Entity Framework console demo doesn't compile

Tags: c#, entity-framework, compiler-errors, entity-framework-5, msdn

I'm new to MVC 3 and am struggling to get Entity Framework 5 to work. (ALL the demoes I try bomb - so, I eventually even tried the Console demo that gets linked to from within VS2010 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878

I already have a reference to 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.

I used SQL Express as in the demo (but had to manually set up the tables since the script wouldn't run in VS2010 where the "Query" opens a designer).

However, when I carefully follow all of the steps in this MSDN Console EF Demo, I get the following 9 errors:

```
Error   1   'DatabaseFirstSample.BloggingContext' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges' and no extension method 'SaveChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFirstSample.BloggingContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\Program.cs   15  12  DatabaseFirstSample
Error   2   'DatabaseFirstSample.BloggingContext': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'    C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\Program.cs   9   14  DatabaseFirstSample
Error   5   'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments  C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\BloggingModel.Context.cs 19  15  DatabaseFirstSample
Error   4   The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\BloggingModel.Context.cs 16  44  DatabaseFirstSample
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'DbModelBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\BloggingModel.Context.cs 23  49  DatabaseFirstSample
Error   8   The type or namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\BloggingModel.Context.cs 28  16  DatabaseFirstSample
Error   9   The type or namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\BloggingModel.Context.cs 29  16  DatabaseFirstSample
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\BloggingModel.Context.cs 14  30  DatabaseFirstSample
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'UnintentionalCodeFirstException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\vb08sbs\DatabaseFirstSample\DatabaseFirstSample\BloggingModel.Context.cs 25  23  DatabaseFirstSample
```

I'm clearly missing something - but WHAT that might be I'd greatly appreciate some help with please.

Alternatively, I understand that the EF causes significant bloat and is slow because of that and have been advised to rather avoid EF and to just use data classes instead - but I can't find anything explaining how to go about that approach as a more efficient alternative to using the EF (since the EF approach seems to be pushed everywhere on the MS sites).

I have inherited a legacy ASP application that uses a SQL Server 2005 database that was recently compromised with SQL Injection that I would like to revamp using MVC 3 with HTML 5 and CSS3 with Responsive Design - but I'm stuck with finding any approach to working with the existing database within MVC that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work on `VS2010`, but big dramas with the Entity Framework issue, too.

There were inconsistencies in Nuget when coming up with the results from the `DbContext` search. Also, installing `SP1` for VS2010 helped as well.

I had my default language initially set as VB.NET, which had to be changed to C# to get the demo to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer my own question, but I've picked up a probable cause, after editing my question to fix the misleading Link instructions which I copied from the sidebar and changed to my URL - (which didn't display properly) and having changed the Tag at the same time to be more appropriate than just C# - (which I eventually had chosen in desperation from a huge list of totally inappropriate tags just to get the post published before our slow Internet connection timed out).

I had tried to use ***Entity Framework*** as a tag but my post couldn't be uploaded because I was informed that I didn't have enough credits to create a new tag and C# was the only semi-usable Tag I could see to select.

However, after trying Entity-Framework as a new tag after my edit, I was confronted with several Entity-Framework versions, and entity-framework-5 had a note about working with Framework 4.5 (and I am still using Framework 4).

There was NO mention of requiring Framework 4.5 that I noticed while getting the Entity Framework via NuGet - it just gave me Entity Framework 5 and I thought well at least I'll have the latest version! (I just had a look again and it lists "NO DEPENDENCIES"!!!)

Now it looks like I need to get Entity Framework 5 uninstalled and get hold of the old Entity Framework for Framework 4 and then it MAY have a chance of working!

PS - I couldn't get Entity Framework 5 uninstalled, but did manage to track down that the latest previous stable version was 4.3.1 and although I couldn't get that via NuGet, I did manage to install it via the command line - and lo and behold - all 9 errors listed above disappeared and suddenly the Console Entity Framework demo worked - at last!

Comment: How did you install your Entity Framework 5? Did you use nuget? If not you should use nuget. The easiest way to install EF5 is just to create a new project and execute "Install-Package EntityFramework" command in the Package Manager Console (Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console). If you don't have Package Manager Console you can install it from http://nuget.org/ (Install NuGet). EF5 bits from NuGet should work in fact with both .NET Framework 4 and .NET Framework 4.5. If you target .NET Framework 4 some features introduced in 4.5 (enums, spatial) will be missing.